# Is there a way to check for Socket parametres instead of going to exception?

Tags: java, sockets, exception, serversocket

If I have a simple server that starts like this.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER);
```

And a simple client that connects to it:

```
socket = new Socket("host", 5081);
```

The host is a string and can be a value like this: "192.168.1.4"
If there is no service with the host "192.168.1.4" it causes `java.net.ConnectException`

Is there a way to prevent the exception and allow for loop that iterates over an array of hosts, and breaks once reached a valid connection, and continue to exception only if the array of hosts has been exhausted without a connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to use a `try...catch` inside a loop.

You can store the exception in a variable and only re-throw it from that variable if you hit the end of the loop without success.